# How to get the log and substraction of a dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe below, and I wanna do a log calculation for all data first and then substract previous line from the next line. How can I realize it in PyCharm?

[image]

Comment: Please share code/data as text, not as images. Your question is too broad/vague, please try to find a solution to the problem before asking for help. See: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in data.columns:
    data[col] = np.log(data[col])
    data[f"{col}_diff"] = data[col] - data[col].shift(1)
```

- make sure that data contains only numerical values with values bigger than 0
- you should probably remove the first line outputed as it contains NaN values